# trying to run regex against semi-colon separated list of words

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a semicolon-separated list of words (about 180,000 words), like so:

```
;test;dog;cat;hello;whatever;
```

How would I get an aray of all words that contains specific substring using regex?
For example - how would I get all words hat contain letter **a**?
I've tried this:

```
preg_match_all('#(?:;).*a.*(?:;)#u', $one_line, $matches);
```

^But it doesn't seem to produce correct results?... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> get all words hat contain letter a?

get the matched group from index 1 using `preg_match_all` method.

```
(\w*a\w*)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eV5aP3/2)

---

If there are multiple words between semicolon then try below regex as suggested by @ anubhava in below comments.

```
[^;a]*a[^;]*
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eV5aP3/3)

Comment: How about `[^;a]*a[^;]*`

Comment: @anubhava with your pattern it will match two words as well. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eV5aP3/3)

Comment: `[^;a]*a[^;]*` will only match each token text assuming `;` is delimiter

Comment: but OP is talking about words only. Let me update my post for that case as well.

Comment: @anubhava thanks It's a great pattern but some what more confusing for me.

Comment: @Dannyboy: good question! It seems that the content of the `\w` character class depends on two things with PHP. If the PCRE library was compiled to take account to the locals, the `\w` character class can match accentued characters *(depending of the locals)*. If you use the `u` modifier for the pattern, the `\w` character class contains all letter and digit characters from all alphabets of the unicode table (and the underscore). An equivalent of `[\pL\pN_]` *(or `\p{Xwd}` in recent pcre implementations)*

Comment: +1 for working solution. For my taste, I would have gone for `[b-z]*+a[b-z]*` (less backtracking and a bit more elegant IMO) :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would tend to two-step this... first, explode the string into an array:

```
$entries = explode (";", $yourstring);
```

Then you can do a clean regex on each component in the array without having to worry about the semi colon:

```
$matches = preg_grep ("/a/" , $entries);
```

Trying to include the delimiter along with the other regex in my experience can make things pretty complicated pretty quickly.

Comment: `explode` is a good idea, but since you are looking for a fixed string *("a")*, I suggest you to compare performances with a `foreach` and `strpos`. *(I haven't tested the two ways, it can be interesting to compare the results)*

Comment: Yeah but that was just an example - I assumed that the regex he's referring to might come from a search query or something so will need to be regex compatable - if it was purely for "a", you're absolutely right I wouldn't be touching preg_grep.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

Braj is correct for the regex example however I wanted to bring up another way to do this might be to split the string by the semicolons.

Ex use something like this:

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

-Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

then you can simply check if each string contains the letter a. I believe that in some cases this may be more efficient. A case where it might be more efficient is if you are looking for words containing 'a','aa', and 'aaa'. You can split the strings into an array then check each string for containing an 'a'. Then you can shorten the strings you need to check for 'aa' and 'aaa'. Just thought I would point out that assuming regex is necessary is not necessarily going to always be beneficial or most helpful